# Directory index is forbidden golang fiber framework

Tags: go, go-fiber

**c.SendFile Not Working**
**Showing on postman that Directory index is forbidden**

```
func GetFile(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    url := c.Params("file")
    return c.SendFile(fmt.Sprintf("./files/%s", url))
}
func DownloadFile(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    url := c.Params("file")
    return c.Download(fmt.Sprintf("./files/%s", url))
}
```

Comment: You may want to paste here the exact error you're seeing. We can only guess what's going here.

Comment: Your program might not have enough permissions to read the directory. Use `ls -lrtha` to figure out the permissions